# Changing log4j to logback for Cassandra?

Tags: logging, nginx, log4j, slf4j, logback

We have a java application created by our developers, that I've been asked to load balance, this application basically takes queries from our web frontend, queries our Cassandra backend, and returns results back to the frontend.

I've got everything set up via Nginx/round robin as far as balancing, however I'm trying to figure out the best way to set up logging since each instance of this application (which run on individual machines) will log whatever activity it is responsible for.

One possible solution would be to share out a central log file via NFS, and allow all the nodes to write to it.  The problem is that we are using log4j and after some research (and some testing) I see that there are some problems and various log entries are cut off/corrupted, so I started looking for a solution.  I've read that logback classic could be used in "prudent" mode which would allow the nodes to lock down the log while writing.

My question is how/can this be implemented without having to rewrite our code (I'm not a developer)?  I know where the configuration files for our logging are, and I know where the log4j-1.2.17.jar and  slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar files live as well (as relates to our application).

Is there a simple way to switch over to logback, or is this something that needs to be modified within the application itself?

PS I can always go the route of having each instance create its own log, but I'm hoping I can figure out a way to allow them to use the same log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have log4j write to slf4j, which in turn will write to logback.  In your classpath, you will need log4j-over-slf4j-xxx.jar, logback-classic-xxx.jar, logback-core-xxx.jar, slf4j-api-xxx.jar.  Then configure logback (logback.xml) to use the appropriate appender(s).

See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

The SLF4J manual has [a page dedicated](http://slf4j.org/legacy.html) to this topic. In short, log4j-over-slf4j will redirect calls made to the log4j API to SLF4J which can than be sent to logback. Note that you will not need to write any code to achieve these redirections.

As for your log4j configuration file, there is an [online tool](http://logback.qos.ch/translator) to convert log4j.properties to logback.xml.